# What is the time duration for GC.stat metrics in Ruby2.0

Tags: ruby, performance, garbage-collection, virtual-machine, ruby-2.0

I am looking at GC.stat metrics and it seems like there are not good official docs about them.

These 2 articles were helpful:

- http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc
- [What do the fields of Ruby's GC.stat mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634370/what-do-the-fields-of-rubys-gc-stat-mean)

Can someone clarify what is the time frame for which the metrics are reported.

eg:

```
 {:count=>258,
 :heap_used=>2186,
 :heap_length=>3202,
 :heap_increment=>1016,
 :heap_live_num=>673453,
 :heap_free_num=>239928,
 :heap_final_num=>0,
 :total_allocated_object=>11211755,
 :total_freed_object=>10538302}
```

Here is what I know and what I don't:

```
 :count=> Since the start of the process 
 :heap_used=> Since ?
 :heap_length=>Since ?
 :heap_increment=>Since ?
 :heap_live_num=>Since ?
 :heap_free_num=>Since ?
 :heap_final_num=>Since ?
 :total_allocated_object=> Since the start of the process
 :total_freed_object=> Since the start of the process
```

Can someone clarify for the metrics with '?' the timeframe. It could be since the start of the process or since the last GC .

I am guessing its all 'Since start of the process' to be consistant, but I want to be sure .

Ruby2.0

Comment: My guess would be that "heap_free_num" is basically the number available right when you made the call to GC.stat (it has that much free space that it will fill before it performs the next GC)

Comment: heap_live_num: updated at each GC.stat call
heap_free_num:  updated at last GC run
heap_final_num: updated at last GC run

Answer (score 0):

Based on the first resource you already posted, we can conclude the following:

- `heap_used`: currently
- `heap_length`: currently
- `heap_increment`: currently (updated if after a GC run there is not enough space)
- `heap_live_num`: currently (updated after each GC run)
- `heap_free_num`: currently (updated after each GC run)
- `heap_final_num`: curently (updated after each GC run)