# How to monitor garbage collection when running Cucumber?

Tags: ruby, garbage-collection, automation, cucumber, ui-automation

I was trying to get verbose GC information for Ruby Cucumber like I can for the JVM.
But I am not sure how to proceed.
I have seen `GC.collections` , `GC.dump` but I am not sure how to use them.
If any one has faced the same issue then please inform me how to get GC dump or GC statistics or verbose GC for Cucumber tests.

Comment: I've never seen `GC.collections` or `GC.dump`. Where did you see those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to watch Ruby's GC work is to use `GC::Profiler`. You can use it with cucumber by putting something like this in features/support/gc.rb:

```
Before do
  GC::Profiler.enable
  GC.start
end

After do
  puts GC::Profiler.report
end
```

If you want more detailed information, assuming you're using MRI (C Ruby), you can get garbage collection statistics from `GC.stat`. You can print information from `GC.stat` after every Cucumber scenario by putting something like this in features/support/gc.rb:

```
After do
  puts "GC: total #{GC.stat[:count]}, major #{GC.stat[:minor_gc_count]}, minor #{GC.stat[:minor_gc_count]}"
end
```

Different versions of Ruby have different garbage collection, so `GC.stat` returns different information. [The `GC.stat` rdoc](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/GC.html#method-c-stat) doesn't document what each hash key means. [A blog post by Sam Saffron](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2013/11/22/demystifying-the-ruby-gc) documents `GC.stat`'s hash keys for Ruby 2.0 (and says that [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12634370/what-do-the-fields-of-rubys-gc-stat-mean) is inaccurate). [A blog post by Thorsten Ball](http://thorstenball.com/blog/2014/03/12/watching-understanding-ruby-2.1-garbage-collector/) documents `GC.stat`'s hash keys for Ruby 2.1.

Comment: Thanks,It is resulting data in a tabular form,but still I could not see specific documentation for different field.

Comment: AFAIK Ruby doesn't document GC stats. That's why I linked to the blog posts.